# Merge / Combine object arrays into single object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object with key values, and those keys each contain an array of objects:

```
var obj = {
  "0": [
    {
      "category": "A",
      "index": 0,
      "property": "Name",
      "value": "Bob"
    },
    {
      "category": "A",
      "index": 0,
      "property": "Surname",
      "value": "Dylan"
    }
  ],
  "1": [
    {
      "category": "A",
      "index": 1,
      "property": "Name",
      "value": "Elvis"
    },
    {
      "category": "A",
      "index": 1,
      "property": "Surname",
      "value": "Presley"
    }
  ]
}
```

How would I go about merging the objects into one single array with the objects combined therein? The objective is to have the result return the following:

```
var obj2 = [
        {
          "category": "A",
          "index": 0,
          "property": "Name",
          "value": "Bob"
        },
        {
          "category": "A",
          "index": 0,
          "property": "Surname",
          "value": "Dylan"
        },
        {
          "category": "A",
          "index": 1,
          "property": "Name",
          "value": "Elvis"
        },
        {
          "category": "A",
          "index": 1,
          "property": "Surname",
          "value": "Presley"
        }
    ]
```

I've tried to make use of LoDash union and join, however to no avail.

Comment: Have you considered using `Object.values(obj)`? --- Also both the "input" and "output" objects have syntax errors. Please may you fix them?

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox. I've tried that, however it still returns multiple arrays instead of a single array with the combined objects inside.

Comment: If it returns multiple arrays, these can be flattened with `.flat()`. `[[1,2],[3,4]].flat() // [1,2,3,4]`

Comment: how does the first object even possible? i get a syntax error trying to make obj equal to the first thing

Comment: Apologies, I haven't slept much. The syntax has been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your example was wrong, and it's actually like below (since what you put in isn't even valid), you can just use `Object.values(obj).flat()`

```js
var obj = {
    "0": [{
      "category": "A",
      "index": 0,
      "property": "Name",
      "value": "Bob"
    }],
    "1": [{
      "category": "A",
      "index": 1,
      "property": "Name",
      "value": "Jessica"
    }]
}

console.log(Object.values(obj).flat())
```